# TFS Build and msbuild

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I have configured a TFS Build using the default template and run my build based on a schedule. I also have a separate msbuild file that needs to be run along with TFS Build for which I have created an InvokeProcess activity that executes a batch file with msbuild command.

However I get exceptions msbuild cannot be recognized as an internal or external command. Is this the right way to do it?

Thanks
Jai

Comment: Have you specified the full pathname to the MSBuild executable?

Comment: Thanks @Nock I just added the full path and it appears to be working now.

Comment: Why don't you use an MSBuild activity instead of taking the long way around with a batch file that runs MSBuild?  You'll get better logging.

Comment: @BrianKretzler I have customized LLBLGen scripts to execute inside my MSBuild file. Can I still execute them? Do you have any examples that I can refer to?